# Two lines of text start from one letter (horizontally and verticaly)

Tags: html, css, typography

I want to make a banner section where text starts from one letter, but goes in different directions. Here's the phrase "Hyggo Home", so Hyggo should stay horizontal and Home should start off the existing letter H from "Hyggo" and go vertically down. I gave a shot with a couple methods, but none of them worked. Any ideas ?

Comment: What didnt work as expected? what exactly did you try?

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/kba6f7se/

Answer (score 0):

There you Go, solution is from CSS

1. create two divs since they can have width and height by defualt
2. First div is hyggo
3. second div home
4. add following style `word-wrap: break-word;` and width based on font size
5. add space between each character of word home
6. Walla enjoy

```html
<div>Hygo</div>
<div style=" word-wrap: break-word; width:12px;">H o m e</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `break-word` if you're putting spaces between each letter, since it will naturally break on a space...

Comment: just incase odd quirk mode kicks in so from my experience it always safe to haev fall back in case expected native behaviour does not kick in. Has occurred zoom in and out or change of view. Most in reposition environment through. Trickery is defining width of the container in which text is.

Comment: @ViyanMd welcome. If solution fits close to what was needed then be kind enough to mark this as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around with `text-orientation` and `writing-mode` in CSS

Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #vertical-text {
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            /* text-orientation: sideways; */
            text-orientation: upright;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Hyggo</p> 
    <p id="vertical-text">ome</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Changing `text-orientation` between sideways & upright you can have different effects like below:

[image]
[image]

More here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-orientation/

Comment: then of course you can move those letters using ```translate``` or whatever way you can do with it to make it look perfect